# Public folder is forbidden in nginx

Tags: nginx, laravel

I successfully deploy my Laravel app to in Digital Ocean. But my CSS & JS file are 403 (Forbidden).
In my console I see the error:

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

How can I give my application permission to access the `CSS`- and `JS`-files, in my Nginx-configuration?

**nginx config**

```
// nginx configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DOMAIN_NAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS;
    root /var/www/name_of_repo/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I tried `sudo chown -R www-data.www-data public`, but still the problem exist.

Currently the site is loaded without `CSS` nor `JS`.

Comment: Hello. A good start to any question or trouble shooting a problem is all the details. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: your nginx uses www-data?  I am used to see "nobody"? PLease check your settings for user and group. (see the configure script)

Comment: It looks like that your `chown`-command is wrong. Shouldn't it be: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public` (colon instead of dot)?

Comment: And to debug it further, can you navigate to your CSS and/or JS-files on the server, and write: `ls -al` and edit your question to add the extra details. It should be a bunch of lines looking something like this: `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2757 Jan 20  2017 x11-common`. This is to show us the owner and permissions of the files, for users and groups.

Comment: When all that's being said, then I would suggest starting by checking your path in the console for the site (in the developer tools). CSS- and JS-files not being loaded is a classic thing - and in my experience, it's usually because the path to the files are wrong. Something like: double slashes ( `https://example.org//path/css-file.css` ). Or still pointing to a development domain. Etc.

Comment: v =  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: ```getrest@getrest:/var/www/getrest/public$ ls -al``` result ```drwxrwxr-x 10 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 18:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 16 getrest  getrest   4096 Mar 31 18:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   593 Mar 31 18:47 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 18:47 assets
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 18:47 css
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data     0 Mar 31 18:47 favicon.ico
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 18:47 files
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 18:47 fonts
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 18:47 images```

Comment: when I remove /.(?!well-known).* { deny all; } worked, but it may have some impact, instead of removing how can I give permission on public directory

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in [your comment](/questions/1400333/public-folder-is-forbidden-in-nginx#comment2428611_1400333), I think the last location block should be this:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
  deny all;
}
```

The first period needs escaped, otherwise it matches any character.